# How to debug my mouse event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so, ive been having a bunch of trouble with the buttons on this page https://greasygrandpa.github.io/god.net/ , whenever you mouseoff the buttons before the icon fades in, it wrecks the whole thing, and doesn't apply the mouseleave event handler function, here's the j-query i used for it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.aa').mouseenter(function (){
    $(this).animate({'width':'90%'}, 1000);
    $(this).children('.fa').delay(670).fadeIn();
    $(this).children('.fa').delay(1000).css('margin-right','40%');
  });
  $('.aa').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).animate({'width':'40%'}, 1000);
    $(this).children('.fa').css('display','none');
    $(this).children('.fa').css('margin-right','0');
  });
  $('.aal').mouseenter(function (){
    $(this).animate({'width':'90%'}, 1000);
    $(this).children('.fa').delay(670).fadeIn();
    $(this).children('.fa').delay(1000).css('margin-left','40%');
  });
  $('.aal').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).animate({'width':'40%'}, 1000);
    $(this).children('.fa').css('display','none');
    $(this).children('.fa').css('margin-right','0');
  });
});
```

.aa and .aal are used to specify different div's based on their side of the screen.
any help is much appreciated, and im sorry if it's something really simple, i'm really new to j-query and couldn't find any solutions anywhere else.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/finish/  Your mouse leave's are just setting the values.  They are not considering that the animations may still be (yet to) processing.  You can use finish in the mouseleave to cancel and remove any animations that might have been left, before you set the values back to their defaults (or whatever).

Comment: thanks man, I knew i was just making a stupid mistake, but for the life of me i couldn't figure out what, i poured over the documentation and everything and i coundn't find anything. But really, thanks, you saved me hours of pulling my hair out over this, and now my website will look like its a tad more professional, thanks again